# Deployment package installing dlls no longer in project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, web-deployment

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for two applications, installing to IIS 7.5 on another server.  Project A is a web forms web application, and Project B is an MVC 4 web application.  During an attempt to set up StateServer between the two applications, I had added a reference to each's .dll in the other's References list.  StateServer was abandoned in favor of using a cookie, and the project .dlls were deleted (I did not notice until the installation process that Project B's references were probably also in the list.  VS seems to have deleted them from the References when the Project B.dll was deleted, since I did not delete those refs manually).

The problem is, the deployment package is still including them. (I'm just troubleshooting Project A, at the moment.)  They are no longer listed in the project's References list, they do not appear in the folder contents under the obj/Release/Package folder, but they DO appear in the installed location after using Deploy -> Import Application in IIS!  This includes Project B.dll, as well as many of it's references, such as DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll.

I've run a search through my entire solution on Project A, and have no references to the Project B.dll.  I've tried setting up a brand new site in IIS, and deploying to that.  I've tried deploying under Staging (QA) and Release configurations, to make sure it wasn't just one of them that was messed up.  Under Package/Publish Web, the settings you may be interested in are "Only files needed to run this application", and "Create deployment package as a zip file".
Running the site gives the error, "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies".  This dll is not in the References list of the project, nor the deployment Package folder, nor the installed location's bin folder.  It runs with no error, locally.
If I simply remove the extra .dlls manually out of the installed location, I get a compilation error when running the site, complaining a variable is not declared: var lotid = <%=defaultLotID %>;  However, this variable is very much declared in the code behind: Public Shared defaultLotID As Integer = 0.  And like I said, it runs fine locally.  So it seems like a bogus error; just a canary in the mine, maybe.

Seriously, what am I missing?  I had no idea how hosed I would be after making a reference to another type of web application.  Thank you to whoever takes on the challenge of troubleshooting this one!  I'm two days in and coworkers are baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up undoing all my changes, putting my code back to the TFS last check in version.  I reintroduced the just the cookie code, built and deployed, I no longer saw the other project's dlls in the installation location.  I guess it wasn't going to work to move forward through the reference and subsequent backout.  Had to rollback to the prior TFS version, and start over.